# Angular.js Error: Unknown provider: $resource

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to configure the current user inside the config part of my angular.js app and am getting the following error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: $resource from manyminds
```

This is how I am passing resource in:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $resource) {
```

I include the resource file before I include the app.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
```

I don't get that error when passing $resource into any of my controllers - only when passing it into config. Can I not use $resource in config?

Answer (score 3):

From the [AngularJS documentation on Modules](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) ("Module Loading & Dependencies" section):

> **Configuration blocks** - get executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be injected into configuration blocks. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.

So, for example, you could inject `$routeProvider` into a `config` block, but not `$route`.

If you need information to be available to a controller before a route changes, you may consider using the `resolve` key of `$routeProvider.when`; if you assign a function to `resolve`, Angular will ensure the function is injected (just like a controller) when it runs the function; if you assign a string Angular will find the injectable of the same name and inject that.